# Why split unit tests and instrumented tests folders in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, integration-testing

Out of curiosity, I am wondering why Android splits instrumented and unit tests folders.

I am well aware of the thus offered ability to have different dependencies for each. Are there any other reasons to do so ?

Answer (score 2):

Well for one, unit test can run on its own (no emulator / device needed), so you can easily run a package full of unit tests vs a package mixed although it is possible to combine them. A typical unit test runs around less than a second while a typical instrument test could run as long as hours etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why splits instrumented and unit tests folders?

- **unittests run fast** (i.e. 100 tests per second) on the pc without the need to deploy them on device/emulator and can therefore be **executed often** (i.e. 100 times a day i.e. after small changes or before checkin-to-sourcecode-repository)
- **instrumentation test are slow** (i.e. 1 test needs 0,5 to 10 seconds) plus deployment on device/emulator is needed (extra 30 seconds). These tests are usually **run not that often** (i.e. at night or at the lunch break)